# Как получить максимальное значение в объекте относительно нуля?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне получить максимальное значение ключа `d`

Из примера ниже видно что значение может быть положительным или отрицательным.

Максимальное это либо положительное максимальное, либо отрицательное относильно 0 (нуля).

И вывести это значение через `Math.abs()` тоесть положительным, если оно было отрицательное

```js
// образец данных, здесь максимальное d это -574815.2999999998
// так как -574815 от 0 оно больше, чем 26496 от 0
let data = {
  1662336000: { 
    0.0357: {
      v: 742397.8, 
      d: 26496.799999999992
    },
    0.0352: {
      v: 1761799.900000001,
      d: -574815.2999999998
    }
  }
};
```

Знаю что можно как то через эту функцию, но не понимаю каким образом это можно реализовать

```
Object.entries(data).reduce((p, c) => {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с переполнением стека не грохнется, то можно так:

```js
let data = {
  1662336000: { 
    0.0357: {
      v: 742397.8, 
      d: 26496.799999999992
    },
    0.0352: {
      v: 1761799.900000001,
      d: -574815.2999999998
    }
  }
}

var res = Math.max(...Object.values(data).flatMap(Object.values).map(x => Math.abs(x.d)))
console.log(res)
```

А можно так:

```js
let data = {
  1662336000: { 
    0.0357: {
      v: 742397.8, 
      d: 26496.799999999992
    },
    0.0352: {
      v: 1761799.900000001,
      d: -574815.2999999998
    }
  }
}

var res = Object.values(data).flatMap(Object.values).reduce((r, {d}) => Math.max(r, Math.abs(d)), 0)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо, красивый короткий код)

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска абсолютного максимума  в массиве:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 10, -11, 3];

const res = array1.reduce(
  (previous, current) => {
    if (Math.abs(previous) > Math.abs(current)) {
      return Math.abs(previous);
    } else {
      return Math.abs(current);
    }
  }
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: А `Math.max` для кого?

Comment: Автор указал, что он хочет использовать функцию reduce

Comment: Ну так `reduce((previous, current) => Math.max(Math.abs(previous), Math.abs(current)))`. Кстати, он не `previous`.

Comment: Ок, согласен по поводу Math.max, но про previous тут так написано https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Там написано `accumulator`...

Comment: А, нашёл, где они в примере назвали `previousValue` - ну и зря они так)